# Install nginx dynamic module using docker compose

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

Usually in nginx to compile a third part module you should use this command:

```
./configure --add--module=path/to/your/new/module/directory
```

Then using:

```
make
```

And finally:

```
make install
```

But using docker I can't go into nginx path and run these commands. How could I add "configure" command to my docker-compose.yml file?

EDIT:
I've tried to create a simple Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM nginx 
RUN ./configure --add-module=./module/ 
     make && \ 
     make install
```

And including it into my docker-compose.yml.

And it gave me this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./configure: not found The command '/bin/sh -c ./configure --add-module=./module/' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I've also tried to use "configure" instead of "./configure", but same result. I don't know how to set configure command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question correctly, but I think `configure`, `make` and `make install` should be done as part of `docker build` using the `RUN` directive (in your `Dockerfile`). `docker-compose` will simply run the resultant image (probably in-tandem with other docker images).

Sample Dockerfile (not verified, may contain errors!):

```
FROM centos:latest
COPY nginx /root/nginx
WORKDIR /root/nginx
RUN ./configure && make && make install
```

Comment: Yes, you've understood my question. You're right, I should use a dockerfile for my purpose and then using docker-compose only for combine different images. 
I've updated my question with your advice, but still I haven't solved my problem.

Comment: `FROM nginx` will start form a base image that already has `nginx` installed. It will likely not have the nginx source code that has the `configure` script and `Makefile`s. The best way would be to start from CentOS or Ubuntu or some such OS image, copy / download nginx source code into it and then run these commands.

Comment: You've written the right method:
First, i started from a official OS image: FROM ubuntu:latest.
Then i downloaded and extracted nginx's binaries.
Then, before compiling, i added my module in "./configure" command.
It worked. Thank you!

Comment: full procedure i.e more details please. any step by step guide?